# Pandas to_sql set column type

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a column with numbers in a String format that I want to send to `PostresSQL` as float. How can I ensure that `SQLAlchemy` sets this column as float? (note that could be a NaN in the column). Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:5432/{}'.format(USER, DB_PW, HOST, DB))

df = pd.DataFrame({'String2Number': ['0,2', '', '0,0000001']})

df.to_sql(name='TABLE_NAME', con=engine, index=False)
```

Comment: I normally create a list from my columns then create a dict passing in the dtypes using sql alchemy `df.column : sa.types.FLOAT` i then pass this dict into the dtype argument in `to_sql` `df.to_sql(... dtype=mydict)`

Comment: @Datanovice thats a great pattern to do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your numbers should be in *decimal point* format, so we need to replace your decimals with comma. 
Next you should ensure that `to_sql` function will use float, and You can achieve this with `dtype` argument that enable to set a column type (based on [sqlalchemy types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/types.html)) when inserting in database. Here the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import Float # note this import to use sqlalchemy Float type

engine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:5432/{}'.format(USER, DB_PW, HOST, DB))

df = pd.DataFrame({'String2Number': ['0,2', '', '0,0000001']})

# Replacing ',' to '.'
df['String2Number'] = df['String2Number'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(',', '.'))

# Set column type as SQLAlchemy Float
df.to_sql(
  name='TABLE_NAME',
  con=engine,
  index=False,
  dtype={'String2Number': Float()}
)
```

Answer (score 4):

`to_sql` have a parameter called `dtype` you can use that to define schema. (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import Float

engine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:5432/{}'.format(USER, DB_PW, HOST, DB))

df = pd.DataFrame({'String2Number': ['0,2', '', '0,0000001']})

df.to_sql(name='TABLE_NAME', con=engine, index=False, dtype={"String2Number": Float()})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try change to dataframe to numeric. Maybe it can help. Example:

```
    df[1] = pd.to_numeric(df[1])
```